# Knockoutjs default loader doesn't show up on first click

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, loading, loader

I'm using a knockoutjs extension to place a loader on top of an element that is loaded from an ajax request so that a loading gif is show while the request is executing.

The [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/t3Kqc/7/) is very basic:

- It loads a list of avatars and shows the loading image while the ajax
  request is executing.
- Then, when you click an avatar, it's details
  are loaded into another placeholder and a loading icon is also shown
  while the request is executing.

The problem is, the very first time I click on an avatar, the loading icon isn't shown but all subsequential clicks works.
What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you are seeing is related to having both `with` and your custom binding on the same element.  When the value is null, the `with` binding clears the child elements.  This removes your loader (although it has already been copied off as part of the "template" used by the `with` binding), but it is put back when you populate `infos`.  Having them on the same element also means that the bindings fires twice (once from changing `infos` and once from updating `isAvatarLoading`.

The easy way to fix this one is to split out the bindings like:

```
<div class="avatar" style="margin-left: 55px;" data-bind="loadingWhen: isAvatarLoading">
    <div data-bind="with: infos">
        <div data-bind="text: firstName"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: lastName"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: age"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: description"></div>
        <div style="margin-left: 55px;" id="" data-bind="with: image">
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: Url }" />
            <div data-bind="text: Description"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to add another element, then you could use the containerless `with` syntax like:

```
<div class="avatar" style="margin-left: 55px;" data-bind="loadingWhen: isAvatarLoading">
    <!-- ko with: infos -->
        <div data-bind="text: firstName"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: lastName"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: age"></div>
        <div data-bind="text: description"></div>
        <div style="margin-left: 55px;" id="" data-bind="with: image">
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: Url }" />
            <div data-bind="text: Description"></div>
        </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Sample: http://fiddle.jshell.net/rniemeyer/75Lyn/